# ASP.NET Learning Path for a PHP Programmer

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm a beginning PHP programmer with little real-world experience (haven't even graduated yet), but I'd like to learn ASP.NET to possibly qualify for twice as many jobs in web development as opposed to knowing just PHP and having seen far too many `!== false` I love the idea of working with a strongly-typed language. I started using the MVC framework CodeIgniter recently, but I can write PHP without a framework, too. I also like to be in control of my HTML. I read an ASP.NET/C# book a couple of months ago, but somehow Web Forms just don't "click" for me. What approach would you recommend for a PHP programmer to ease into ASP.NET?

Comment: Forgot to add: I do know some C# and can write simple desktop apps in C#. I'm looking to learn doing web development in C# specifically.

Comment: knowing c# would be a good advantage. i jumped from PHP into ASP.NET C# the hard way. So you have to remember that any webpage on ASP.NET is like a Form - server/client - they interact together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have experience with an MVC framework, why not give [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) a look? You can certainly take advantage of your C# knowledge with it and there are plenty of docs and tutorials on that site and many questions/answers related to it here on SO.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC will also give you more control over HTML than you have with ASP.NET web forms. There are several good books, but the WROX book is definitely one to check out; it was written by the ASP.NET MVC development team.

Comment: I agree - MVC will be much more familiar to someone from a PHP background than web-forms. However, a basic understanding of web-forms would be useful, too.

Comment: Hi @Marcus89, so finally have switched to asp.net or are you still working with PHP ? Do let me know.